# SQL / PHP calculate percent of Votes

Tags: php, sql, calc

On on website I run, I let users rate the our website.
I do I save the data in database. There are 8 different answer. How can i get the percentage of votes of each value.

my table looks like this

id-----vote
1-------p1

2-------p1

3-------p2

4-------p3

5-------p4

6-------p3

...

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySql? MS SQL? Oracle?

Comment: can you please give clearer data? p1 is a feature, a number of votes? where are stored the feature? the user ids? the vote counts?...

Comment: Without knowing any more detail: (100 / total_vote_count * vote_type)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
select vote, 
       count(*) / (select count(*) from your_table) * 100 as percentage
from your_table
group by vote
```

Comment: In that case, you really should explain your data structure. It is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a table `polls`, in which a `voteid` field says what preference was issued for that one vote.

Your best option, I think, is to simply run

```
SELECT voteid, count(voteid) AS votes FROM polls GROUP BY voteid;
```

and then recover the data in PHP:

```
$votes = array();
$total = 0;
while($vote = mysql_fetch_array($exec)) // or PDO, or ...
{
    list($voteid, $num) = $vote;
    $votes[$voteid] = $num;
    $total += $num;
}
// Convert absolute number to percentages
$percents = array();
foreach($votes as $vote => $count)
    $percents[$vote] = number_format(($count*100.0)/$total, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a two folds way IMO, one gets the data, the other shows it but here goes:

```
SELECT vote, count(vote)
FROM votes
GROUP BY vote WITH ROLLUP
```

This will give you all your vote counts (Doesn't include the answers without votes, you have to infer them or change your model) and the last line that has a NULL vote will be your total votes all at once.

So you place those in memory as you should always do, pass this on to your display method (view, template, wathever you use) and this one will:

```
echo $voteCount / $totalVotes * 100;
```

Cheers